# jquery if class then hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, toggleclass

I have a click handler that toggles a class, and a hover effect that changes a background color. 
I'd like to disable the hover effect if the class has been toggled.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $('#plan td.n').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected n');
});

$('#tblThings td.n').hover(function()
{
  if ( $( this ).hasClass( "selected" ) )
  {
          $( this ).css('background-color', '#63D3FF');
  }
};
```

Many thanks for your time

Comment: It's not really clear if `td.n` is always the same element, just with two different parents, or what? Maybe you should post some HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to check the same elements for the class?

```
$('#plan td.n').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected n');
});

$('#tblThings td.n').hover(function() {
    if ( $('#plan td.n').hasClass( "selected" ) ) {
        $( this ).css('background-color', '#63D3FF');
    }
});
```